# Sine Function without any library

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new at learning c++. Because of curiosity, I created a sine function without using any library (except iostream, to take input and output). Here is the code that I wrote, and it works perfectly.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int factorial(int n);
double sin(double x, int n);
double pow(double x, int n);
int main(){
    double num;
    int n;
    cout << "Enter any Number" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Enter n" <<  endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "sine of given x equals " << sin(num, n);
}
int factorial(int n){
    int a=1;
    for(int p=1; p<=n; p++){
        a=a*p;
    }
        return a;
}
double sin(double x, int n){
    double sine=0;
    for ( int a=1, b=1; a<n+n+1; a+=2, b++){
        sine=sine + (pow(-1, b+1))*(pow(x,a))/(factorial(a));
    }
    return sine;
}
double pow(double x, int n){
    double num=1;
    for (int a=1; a<=n; a++){
        num=num*x;
    }
    return num;
}
```

It uses taylor series to calculate sine. I also takes 'n' as number of terms to include from taylor series to improve accuracy. I have certain doubts in this

1) the sin function i created, I found by trial and error that in the for loop, I have to write 'a< n+n+1' , but If I tried to write 'a<2n+1' it gives me ugly compilation error. Why is it so? What can I do to make it that way?

2)If I try to enter large values of n (>15-16) it gives answer as 'nan'. Why is it so? I think double has huge capacity of storing numbers (10^408). Correct me If I'm wrong. Or what can be done to make it calculate for huge value of n.

3) I know the code I written is ugly, I don't want to use any library functions. Anyway what can I do to make this code do better in terms of algorithm. Is there any other efficient way without using any library.

4) Any other comments/hints/tips for learning more in future?

Comment: I'm curious how many people read past "it works perfectly".

Comment: The problem in 2) might be because of the `factorial` function using an `int`. The range for `double` is large, but not for `int`.

Comment: @Catalyst, it did really..

Comment: @Bo Persson, Thanks for pointing that

Comment: The compiler will optimize the code a<n+n+1 so it won't make a difference for the program but change it as suggested if you think it's more readable.

Comment: Don't call your function  `sin`  but something else (`my_sin` perhaps) because `sin` is already defined in the standard library; Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: There is a fascinating discussion of how prime numbers can generate sine waves in the book The Music of the Primes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Music_of_the_Primes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `a < 2*n +1`.
2. factorial of 15 is `1,307,674,368,000`. That number cannot be represented by an `int`. You have to rethink the code you use to compute the terms of the Taylor series for `sine`.
3. It will be better to post your working code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get feedback on how to improve your code.

N-th term in the Taylor series expansion is `(-1)^(N-1)x^(2*N+1)/(2*N+1)!`
(N+1)-th term is `(-1)^(N)x^(2*(N+1)+1)/(2*(N+1)+1)!`

`T(N+1) = -1*T(N)*x^2/((2*(N+1)+1)*(2*(N+1))`

When you use this logic, you don't need to need `pow` or `factorial`. You derive the (N+t)-th term from the N-th term very easily. The starting point, `T(0)` is simply `x`.

Here's an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double sin(double x, int n)
{
   double t = x;
   double sine = t;
   for ( int a=1; a<n; ++a)
   {
      double mult = -x*x/((2*a+1)*(2*a));
      t *= mult;
      sine += t;
   }
   return sine;
}

int main()
{
    double num;
    int n;
    cout << "Enter any Number" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Enter n" <<  endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << std::setprecision(20) << "sine of given x equals " << sin(num, n) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
3.5
5
```

Output:

```
sine of given x equals -0.32838899588879211233
```

Sample input:

```
3.5
20
```

Output:

```
sine of given x equals -0.35078322768961955891
```

Sample input:

```
3.5
200
```

Output:

```
sine of given x equals -0.35078322768961955891
```

P.S. There is no change in output when N is changed from 20 to 200.

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for...! Thanks

Comment: Given that `sin()` is between `-1` and `1`, you might want to comment on the significance of getting values with magnitude `1.78`.    I haven't checked your code, but that result smells wrong given the convergence properties of the Taylors series, and that `sin(3.5 radians)`  is about `-0.3508`.

Comment: @Peter, it was wrong. My use of `a` and `t` were not compatible. I needed to change the `for` loop. The answers are different, and more accurate, now.

Answer (score 3):

1) You need to write

```
 a < 2*n+1
```

You can use recursion functions to do the code more nice and clear.

Answer (score 3):

You would be hard pressed to convince anyone of your claim it "works perfectly", particularly since you go on to describe problems.

1)  is a basic misunderstanding on your part with expressions.  `2n+1` does not double `n` and add `1` to it, in C++.   The correct expression is (presumably) `2*n + 1`.   Go back and read any elementary introduction to C++ to understand why.

2)   Your method of computing `sin()` raises a value to a large power.   If you're raising a value to the 16th power, it doesn't take a particularly large value to overflow most floating point representations i.e. produce a value larger than the floating point type can represent.  The result of that is undefined in C++, but with IEEE representations the result is a `NaN`.

2a)  A problem you have missed is that `factorial()` grows very fast.  A 16-bit signed `int` (which corresponds to the minimum required) will overflow when calculating `8!`.  A 32 bit signed integer (common in practice, but not guaranteed) will overflow when computing `13!`.   Even a 64-bit signed `int` (which does exist with some compilers) will overflow when calculating `21!`.   The result of overflowing a (built-in) signed integral type is undefined behaviour.   Picking a larger sized integer won't address this, since factorial grows faster for larger values - not that changing from a 32-bit integer to a 64-bit integer only improves ability to calculate factorials between `14` and `20`.

3)    The big problem is that you are expecting to be able to compute big values (which overflow variables), divide them, and get a mathematically sane result.  Computers don't work that way.    And remove from your consciousness any concept that using your `pow()` or `factorial()` is required - if either of those overflow, dividing their results is pointless (and, in your case, both probably are overflowing).    What you need to do is look at the consecutive terms in the Taylor series, and exploit mathematical relationships between them.

The first term in the Taylor's series (when computing `sin(x)`) is `x`.  The second is `-x^3/3!`  [using `^` to represent "to the power of", although that is not valid C++].   The third is `+x^5/5!`.   The fourth is `-x^7/7!`.     Consider what the relationship is between the first and second terms.  Then consider what the relationship is between the second and third terms.   Generalise that, and you will have a method to compute `sin()` using the Taylors series with significantly reduced risk of overflowing something.

And, if anyone tried to tell you to use a "huge integer" (an integral type that has no upper bound) and a "huge floating point type", ignore them.   Yes, those things have their place, but you are better off avoiding the need for them if you can.   It is possible to avoid that need in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my examples from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine) using Taylor expansion, I think these are the fastest possible. you can delete last lines that contains `t += ...` for low precision and high performance:

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
inline float Sin(float x) 
{
    // if x is in between -pi and pi no need to fmod
    //x = fmodf(x + M_PI, 2.0f * M_PI) - M_PI; 
    float xx = x * x * x; // x^3
    float t = x - (xx  / 6.0f); // 6 = !3
    t += (xx *= x * x) / 120.0f; // 120 = !5
    t -= (xx *= x * x) / 5040.0f; // 5040 = !7 
    t += (xx * x * x)  / 362880.0f; // 362880 = !9 
    return t;
}

inline float Cos(float x) 
{
    //x = fmodf(x + M_PI, 2.0f * M_PI) - M_PI;
    float xx = x * x; // x^2
    float t = 1.0f - (xx / 2.0f); // 2 = !2
    t += (xx *= x * x) / 24.0f;  // 24.0f = !4
    t -= (xx *= x * x) / 720.0f; // 720.0f = !6
    t += (xx * x * x) / 40320.0f; // 40320 = !8
    return t;
}
```

edit:
you can find my other trigonometric functions here: [github link](https://github.com/benanil/CLRayTracer/blob/master/CLRayTracer/Math/Math.hpp)